# SQL Trigger To Replace Null Values in table with Current Date on INSERT?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, triggers

I'm writing a trigger that replaces any `NULL` values inserted into the `dates` (of type `DATE`) column of my `Appointments` table.  But I can't figure out how to insert the current date.

My trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER appointment_date_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON appointments
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.dates IS NULL)
BEGIN
     :NEW.dates := NOW();
END;
/
```

The above gives me the error in the compiler log:

> NOW() must be declared

I also tried using `GETDATE()` instead of `NOW()` but it gives the same error in the compiler log as above.

---

To test this trigger, my sample `INSERT` query with `NULL` value for `dates` column is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO appointments
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', NULL);
```

My `appointments` table only has 4 columns:  `patient_ID`, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `dates`

Ideally, the end-result should have a new row inserted into the `appointments` table as follows:

> 1 | John | Doe | 04-21-2017

With the current date replacing the `NULL` value

---

**EDIT**:  I'm not permitted to alter any original table structures, including `DEFAULT` values, otherwise I wouldn't have needed to ask this question in the first place....

Comment: Can you modify the table so the date field has a default value of getdate()?

Comment: no.  altering of any original tables is not permitted.  A trigger must be used.

Comment: In Oracle we use `SYSDATE` to get the current date:  `:new.dates := sysdate;`

Answer (score 1):

*Edit* This solution with `now()` does not work without a synonym for `now()`.

You can use `COALESCE` to replace the `:NEW` date with `NOW()` if it is `NULL`, but otherwise leave it alone:

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENTS(PATIENT_ID NUMBER, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(64), LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(64), DATES DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER appointment_date_insert
BEFORE INSERT
  ON appointments
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :NEW.DATES := COALESCE(:NEW.DATES,NOW());
  END;
/
```

Then test it:

```
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', NULL);
INSERT INTO appointments VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', SYSDATE - 100);

SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENTS;

PATIENT_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  DATES      
1           John        Doe        21-APR-17  
2           Jane        Doe        11-JAN-17
```

As alternatives to `NOW()`, you might consider `SYSDATE` (or `CURRENT_DATE` if you prefer)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER appointment_date_insert
BEFORE INSERT
  ON appointments
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :NEW.DATES := COALESCE(:NEW.DATES,SYSDATE);
  END;
/
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried that already and it still tells me that `NOW` must be declared.  Same for `GETDATE`.

Comment: Thanks @5120bee that is interesting.  I'll update the post with another alternative or two.  Can you tell me what version of oracle you are using?

Comment: I have 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: Thanks @5120bee.  Updating now.  Does this alternative work for you?

Comment: There is no `NOW()` in Oracle; rather, there is `SYSDATE`.

Comment: @mathguy I believe now is supported in oracle and was there in 11g as well.  My example is functional.  Did you run my example?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks!  Something so simple... I feel stupid. :/

Comment: I just ran `select now() from dual` and it threw an exception - `now()` is not recognized. I am on 12.1, so it's not an old version.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy that is interesting.  Here's what I get [
SQL> SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL; 
NOW()      
21-APR-17  ].

Comment: I don't doubt that. What I do doubt is that you are using Oracle. What do you get if you run `select * from v$version`? (If you get an error then you are definitely not using Oracle.)

Comment: Thanks @mathguy.  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @mathguy this is interesting.  Do you have any idea why we'd get a discrepancy here?  I get the same in sqlplus and sqlcl and wouldn't have imagined there was config to enable now() anywhere.

Comment: @mathguy  ah there it is:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBA_SYNONYMS WHERE SYNONYM_NAME  = 'NOW';    gets a hit.  Got a public synonym I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      to_char((JOINING_DATE),'DD-MON-YYYY') IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 
      to_char((JOINING_DATE),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
    ELSE 
      '-' 
  END
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no NOW() function in the oracle database, instead, you can use SYSDATE or CURRENT_DATE. The difference between two functions is in the following [Oracle Community link].([https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2217249/sysdate-vs-current-date#:~:text=sysdate%20is%20the%20current%20date,getting%20the%20result%20as%200.](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2217249/sysdate-vs-current-date#:%7E:text=sysdate%20is%20the%20current%20date,getting%20the%20result%20as%200.))!

you can use this code to create your trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER appointment_date_insert BEFORE
  INSERT ON appointments FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF inserting AND :NEW.dates IS NULL THEN
      :NEW.dates:= sysdate;
    END IF;
  END;
```